# What are allowed HTML in wp_kses_post function?

Tags: wordpress

I need to sanitize the output of admin_notices which uses certain things like

- a
- id
- href
- title
- strong

Is it good idea to use `wp_kses_post` function?

Reading docs I am uncertain what HTML tags are allowed https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_kses_post/

Answer (score 3):

To check the list of allowed tags and attributes for `wp_kses_post` you can use

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r( wp_kses_allowed_html( 'post' ) );
echo '</pre>';
die();
```

In your case, where only `a` and `strong` allowed, you can use `wp_kses` function ([docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_kses/)) instead

```
$allowed_html = [
    'a' => [
        'id' => true,
        'href'  => true,
        'title' => true,
    ],
    'strong' => [],
]; 
$clear_post = wp_kses( $post, $allowed_html );
```

Comment: exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

`wp_kses_post` allows all **HTML** that is permitted in post content. So it will load a large array which is redundant in your case. As you need only some specific HTML tags to be sanitized, you should use the `wp_kses` function as you have control here and you can mention which HTML tags should be allowed. You can do as follows-

```
$allowed_tags = [
    'a' => [
        'id'    => true,
        'href'  => true,
        'title' => true,
    ],
    'strong' => [],
]; 
$sanitized_post = wp_kses( $post, $allowed_tags );
```