# How can I sanitize custom fields that accept all standard values and tags like the default WordPress editors (post creation or new product)?

Tags: php, wordpress

My question is related to this answer to one of my previous questions: 
[Custom metabox content displayed in single product additional tabs on Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52895826/custom-metabox-content-displayed-in-single-product-additional-tabs-on-woocommerc/52896790#52896790)

and here the code line that save a custom value filtering the html:

```
update_post_meta( $post_id, '_cost_performance', wp_kses_post($_POST[ '_cost_performance' ]) );
```

This post is related to my question:
[What are allowed HTML in wp_kses_post function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66561592/what-are-allowed-html-in-wp-kses-post-function)

WordPress and WooCommerce have default text editors that accept all standard tags and values (for example, when you press Enter in your WordPress or WooCommerce editor, it is moved down or go to next line by `&nbsp`) I want my editors to be like this and accept all the standard values.

I use the **`wp_kses_post`** function for this, but it does not accept some tags, for example **`<br>`**, **`&nbsp`** and... and every tag that is needed must be defined for this function, is there a solution did you define all the standard tags at once for this function so that you don't need to enter the desired tags one by one? (So I want to define all tags and standard values for `wp_kses_post` without having security problem)

The **`esc_html`** function is not the answer for my work because I want all the tags to be executed on the user side and not just the tags themselves to be printed as text, for example, I use the following command:

```
<strong>Hello</strong>
```

In esc_html, the text is output:

```
<strong>Hello</strong>
```

While the value should be the following:

> **Hello**

So this **`esc_html()`** function does not work for me.

Comment: You realise wordpress is open source?https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/kses.php shows you exactly how that function works. The question about editors is a separate issue.

Comment: Before asking questions to this authority:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_kses_post/#source
I had gone but I had not succeeded
How should I use this command to remove all limitations of standard tags?

Comment: Dear @LoicTheAztec, I'm sorry, can you answer my question? thank you

Comment: Dear @AdamLuper, I am sorry, but you will have to build a custom sanitizing function using wp_kses() and setting all desired allowed tags and attributes…

Comment: @LoicTheAztec, Is it possible for you to send me a beginner's example or an example related to my question as an answer to this question? Because I still haven't found a suitable solution and I don't know how to define all my default and personal tags.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec, I want my personal editor to be similar to the default editor of WordPress, that is, almost everything that the default editor of WordPress accepts, my editor also accepts.